# How do i skip an if statement if the input doesnt match it?

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("""
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Welcome to the Garden Grass Calculator
Please Follow the instructions, and the size, and cost of your grass 
will be calculated!
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
""")

measurement = str(input("Have you measured in feet, inches, meters, or centimeters?: "))

if measurement == "inches":
    feet2 = float(input("Input your value in inches: "))
    result = (feet2//12)
    print ("Your result is" + (str(result) + (str("feet"))))

elif measurement == "centimeters":
    meters2 = float(input("Input your value in centimeters: "))
    result = (meters2//100)
    print ("Your result is " + (str(result) + (str("meters"))))

    
elif measurement == "meters" or "feet":
    print("Awesome, you know what youre doing!")

else:
    print("That is not a valid measurement: ")

shape = input("What is the Shape of your space?: ")

if "shape" == "square" or "rectangle":
    len = float(input("What is the length of the space?: "))
    width = float(input("What is the width of the space?: "))
    calc = (len*width)
    print(calc)

elif "shape" == "circle":
    rad = float(input("What is your area radius?: "))
    pi = ("3.1415")
    calc2 = (pi*(rad*rad))
    print (calc2)

else:
    print("Please input square, rectangle or circle:")
```

Im trying to write it so that when i input that my shape is a circle, i can skip straight to the circle elif statement, howerver when i run this, it comes up with an output as if i had written the input as a square.
Im certain im just being stupid but its gone unresolved for hours. i only have ~5 hours python experience

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: I just tried it, its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i think your if statement are not well written.
Indeed, instead of :
`if x =='a' or 'b':` you should do `if x=='a' or x=='b:'`

Secondly you are totally not using the shape variable,
instead you are just checking if the string `"shape"` == `"another string"`
Which will obvisouly returns false

So things you have to change :

```
shape = input("What is the Shape of your space?: ")

if shape == "square" or shape == "rectangle":
    len = float(input("What is the length of the space?: "))
    width = float(input("What is the width of the space?: "))
    calc = (len*width)
    print(calc)

elif shape == "circle":
    rad = float(input("What is your area radius?: "))
    pi = ("3.1415")
    calc2 = (pi*(rad*rad))
    print (calc2)

else:
    print("Please input square, rectangle or circle:")
```